# В Вики «икéя» со строчной, где проверить?

Tags: прописная-строчная, заимствования

> IKEA (торговая марка в России — ИКЕА, в бытовой речи часто произносят
>   как «икéя») — нидерландская производственно-торговая группа компаний
>   (имеет шведские корни), владелец одной из крупнейших в мире торговых
>   сетей по продаже мебели и товаров для дома. Полное наименование — IKEA
>   International Group. Штаб-квартира — в городе Делфте, провинция Южная
>   Голландия.

У меня:

> Лопатки у нас не нашлось. Лишними оказались только завалящие четыре
>   ложки, но **из Икеи** – они бы точно не справились. Ведь у аканта
>   такой серьёзный корень, что просто так из земли не выдернешь!

Понижать? кавычить? иностранить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все прописные на латинице и не склоняйте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При письменной передаче неформальной речи для меня убедителен только вариант **"Икея"**, со склонением для выражений вроде *купила в "Икее"* и подобных; с видовым же наименованием - "*в магазине "Икея*". Без склонения и изменения фонетики формальная транслитерация "ИКЕА" (без склонения) подходит только для официальных ссылок и рекламы, в бытовой же речи это звучит крайне неестественно: не говорим же мы ***он приехал на "Мерседес"*** - хотя формально это несклоняемое женское имя, и кому-то когда-то наверняка хотелось всех на этот счёт просветить и заставить уважать этимологию. В нашем случае устное словоупотребление уже сложилось, а запись попросту должна соответствовать фонетике.

Answer (score 0):

> В Вики «икéя» со строчной

Нет, в Вики написано правильно — все буквы прописные. Со строчной указано, как это название зачастую произносится. Дело в том, что фонетически строчная буква ничем не отличается от прописной.

Склонение типа "ложки из ИКЕИ" выглядит ничем не лучше, чем, например, "поехать в СШУ" (вместо "поехать в США"). Впрочем, если нужно подчеркнуть особую просторечность стиля, тогда не уверен, поскольку так действительно говорят.